# Switch label and input in TYPO3 7.6 form

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.x, typo3-7.6.x

In TYPO3 7.4 it was possible to switch label and input in a form. For some reason this has been changed in 7.5 and 7.6.

```
class = form
enctype = multipart/form-data
id = contact
method = post
layout {
            checkbox (
                    <input />
                    <label />
            )
}
prefix = tx_form
confirmation = 0
```

Is this a known bug or is there a new way to do this?

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

EXT:form was completely rewritten in 7.5. The whole frontend rendering was replaced by extbase and fluid.

Unfortunately, not all changes have been documented, yet. Some weeks ago, I did a major cleanup of the documentation which can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/. The [layout section](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/Configuration/Layout/LayoutViewSpecific/Index.html) is even more interesting for you. The linked document will explain, how to set up a view specific layout.

But using .layout stuff via TypoScript is not the best way anymore, when it comes to the customization of the layout in TYPO3 7.6. As the [changelog](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6/typo3/sysext/core/Documentation/Changelog/7.5/Feature-69401-AdoptFormToSupportTheExtbaseFluidMVCStack.rst) shows, you should use fluid. The following examples depicts a form with some of the new features. I'm setting globally an additional partial path. But it is also possible to set a partial path for a specific form element (see element "900").

```
plugin.tx_form {
    view {
        # set up additional partial path
        partialRootPaths.20 = EXT:generic_lib/Resources/Private/Extensions/Form/Partials/
    }
}

# build contact form
lib.default_contact_form = FORM
lib.default_contact_form {
    prefix = {$content.mailform.prefix}
    confirmation = 1
    # want to work on a clean base without .layout settings
    compatibilityMode = 0

    postProcessor {
        1 = mail
        1 {
            recipientEmail = {$content.mailform.recipientEmail}

            senderNameField = name
            senderEmailField = email

            ccEmail = TEXT
            ccEmail {
                # depends on the fact that email is required and tested
                data = GP:tx_form_form|{$content.mailform.prefix}|email
                htmlSpecialChars = 1
            }

            subject = TEXT
            subject {
                value = [{$website.title}] - Kontakt
                lang.en = [{$website.title}] - Contact
                lang.es = [{$website.title}] - Contacto
                lang.it = [{$website.title}] - Contatto
            }
        }

        2 = redirect
        2.destination = {$content.mailform.redirectPage}
    }

    10 = TEXTLINE
    10 {
        name = name
        required = required
        type = text
        label.data = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang.xlf:name
        placeholder.data = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang.xlf:name
    }

    20 = TEXTLINE
    20 {
        name = email
        type = email
        required = required
        label.data = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang.xlf:email
        placeholder.data = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang.xlf:email
    }

    30 = TEXTAREA
    30 {
        name = message
        cols = 40
        rows = 5
        required = required
        data-foo = bar
        label.data = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang.xlf:message
        placeholder.data = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang.xlf:message
    }

    900 = TEXTLINE
    900 {
        name = honeypot
        type = text
        label.data = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang.xlf:spam
        placeholder.data = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang.xlf:spam
        autocomplete = off
        partialPath = FlatElements/Honeypot
        # hide field in confirmation and mail views
        visibleInConfirmationAction = 0
        visibleInMail = 0
    }

    1000 = SUBMIT
    1000 {
        name = submit
        value.data = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang.xlf:submit
        class = button
    }

    rules {
        1 = required
        1 {
            element = name
            message.data = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang.xlf:required
            error.data = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang.xlf:mandatory
        }

        2 = email
        2 {
            element = email
            message = (max.muster@domain.com)
            error.data = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang.xlf:mandatory_email
        }
    }
}
```

You can join [typo3.slack.com](https://forger.typo3.org/slack) and open the ext-form channel, if you need any further assistance. Over there, you will find more examples and instant help.